# Searching for Paypal records by paymentId at Paypal account

Tags: php, paypal

I have a site that uses the Paypal Rest API SDK and successfully capture the paymentId after the transaction.

I capture it from the return_url's $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] using PHP.

I was hoping my Client would be able to then go into their Paypal account and search for records using these PaymentID's. It doesn't seem the case. There is a TransactionID but it does not match the PaymentID.

Any idea how to either:

1. Search for the record in a Paypal Account using the PaymentID (using the Paypal Account interface record tools - not api programming)
2. Grab the transactionID after the transaction (the return URL only gives me PaymentID, Token, and PayerID.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that I will need to take the PaymentID and use the SDK to retrieve more detailed payment information.

$apiContext = $this->getApiContext();

```
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment = $payment->get( $paymentId, $apiContext );

        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId( $_GET['PayerID'] );

        // ### Retrieve payment
        // Retrieve the payment object by calling the
        // static `get` method
        // on the Payment class by passing a valid
        // Payment ID
        // (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
        try {

            $payment->execute( $execution, $apiContext );

            if ( $payment ) {

                $obj               = json_decode( $payment );

               //GET SOME STUFF

                $paypal_payment_id = $obj->{'id'};
                $status            = $obj->{'state'};

               //DO SOMETHING WITH IT

            }

        } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
            // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
            //ResultPrinter::printError("Get Payment", "Payment", null, null, $ex);
            log_message( 'error', 'error=' . $ex );
            //exit(1);
        }
```